# Wrong $modal being injected by Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

Im trying to create a modal via Angular, but whenever I run the function I get the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at h.root.RootController.$scope.openModal
```

Which is the following (abridged) code:

```
RootController = ($scope, $http, $state, $modal) ->
     $scope.openModal = -> $modal.open(
         templateUrl: 'partials/modals/myModal.html'
          controller: 'myModal'
        )
```

Seems fairly straight forward, but it isn't working. What really throws me off though is when I debug this in chrome. Per the [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal), `The $modal service has only one method: open(options)`. So when I put a breakpoint on the `openModal` line, I expect to see a `$modal` object with just one property: open. However, this is what I see:

[image: This is not the $modal I was looking for!]

This modal object has a ton of functions, and none of them are `open`. So I'm guessing that Angular is injecting the wrong $modal into my controller, but I have no idea why or how to fix it.

Comment: It seems that `$state` is injected in the place of `$modal`. (These are the methods from `$state`, aren't they?) Could it be that Typescript is inserting something in the method signature (the `this` perhaps to cater for the lambda)?

Comment: Assuming you said that it's you're 'abridged' code, does the actual code have the options wrapped in { } in the open call `$modal.open({
         templateUrl: 'partials/modals/myModal.html'
          controller: 'myModal'
        })`

Comment: @JohnNiedzwiecki Its written in CoffeeScript, so it gets compiled down to the proper form with `{}`.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos You seem to be correct. My array of dependencies lists `[...'$modal', '$state'...]`, but my controller parameters are `(...$state, $modal...)`, so perhaps that is why. But I thought that order didnt have to match?

Comment: No, no, order matters! Hopefully this is your problem...